# I want daterange picker as well as output data in as "DD/MM/YYYY" format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, momentjs

I want the [daterange picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) should me the format as "DD/MM/YYYY " and also take same format while selecting date range as well as the data inside the table also should be in same format and when a user select the date, the output in the data should show it in as "DD/MM/YYY" format.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<input id="daterange">

<table id="table_1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1.</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Set 1</td>
      <td data-order="1558358405">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set2</td>
      <td data-order="1558357779">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set3</td>
      <td data-order="1558348464">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set4</td>
      <td data-order="1558348282">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set5</td>
      <td data-order="1558106170">17/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set6</td>
      <td data-order="1558106062">17/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set7</td>
      <td data-order="1558090241">17/052019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set8</td>
      <td data-order="1556704125">01/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(function() {
  var table = $("#table_1").DataTable();

  // Date range vars
  minDateFilter = "";
  maxDateFilter = "";

  $("#daterange").daterangepicker();
  $("#daterange").on("apply.daterangepicker", function(ev, picker) {
    minDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.startDate);
    maxDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.endDate);

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var date = Date.parse(data[1]);

      if (
        (isNaN(minDateFilter) && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
        (isNaN(minDateFilter) && date <= maxDateFilter) ||
        (minDateFilter <= date && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
        (minDateFilter <= date && date <= maxDateFilter)
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    table.draw();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the `locale` option of the plugin which [documentations you will find here](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options). The solution could be like that

```js
$(function() {
  var table = $("#table_1").DataTable();

  // Date range vars
  minDateFilter = "";
  maxDateFilter = "";

  $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
    locale: {
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    }
  });
  
  $("#daterange").on("apply.daterangepicker", function(ev, picker) {
    minDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.startDate);
    maxDateFilter = Date.parse(picker.endDate);

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var date = Date.parse(data[1]);

      if (
        (isNaN(minDateFilter) && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
        (isNaN(minDateFilter) && date <= maxDateFilter) ||
        (minDateFilter <= date && isNaN(maxDateFilter)) ||
        (minDateFilter <= date && date <= maxDateFilter)
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    table.draw();
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<input id="daterange">

<table id="table_1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1.</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Set 1</td>
      <td data-order="1558358405">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set2</td>
      <td data-order="1558357779">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set3</td>
      <td data-order="1558348464">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set4</td>
      <td data-order="1558348282">20/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set5</td>
      <td data-order="1558106170">17/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set6</td>
      <td data-order="1558106062">17/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set7</td>
      <td data-order="1558090241">17/052019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Set8</td>
      <td data-order="1556704125">01/05/2019</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```